# D3D11CreateDevice leads to syntax error

Tags: c++, directx11

I'm following the book *Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11* by Frank Luna ([link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936420228)) and I'm trying to make the empty project in Chapter 4 (don't worry, I don't expect you to read the book)

I'm getting to the point in code where I need to create the Direct3D device context. My code looks at this so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <D3D11.h>
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>

UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
ID3D11Device* md3dDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext* md3dImmediateContext;
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(0, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 0, createDeviceFlags, 0, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &md3dDevice, &featureLevel, &md3dImmediateContext);

if (FAILED(hr)) {
    MessageBox(0, L"D3D11CreateDevice Failed", 0, 0);
}

// I added this as the entrypoint for the program - copied directly from microsoft's website
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting some errors that make no sense at all. Take a look (by the way, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015):

```
Code    Description                                              File       Line
C2059   syntax error: 'if'                                       main.cpp   16
C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'                     main.cpp   16
C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)    main.cpp   16
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your code above the `WinMain` function inside the function.